# add a server alias to the domain's VHOST?

Tags: apache, dns, alias, vhosts

I have a VPS. I hosted a domain ipointing to a sub directory of the www folder. The domain works fine till the home page. The moment I start going to other pages its shows my servers [orginalname]/[subdirectory name] . I think I need to add a server alias to the domain's VHOST. Can anyone tell me how to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Apache?
Try with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/document/root"
   ServerName name1
   ServerAlias name2
 ...
```

Comment: i have added this to the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled 
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/[]subfoldername/
ServerName .......
ServerAlias ........
# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
~

Answer (score 2):

I did it using the proxy Apache option, this is it:

My VirtualHost is `http://dlx/` and I want to add an "alias" like `http://dlx/drupal/`

In the `httpd.config` file I added a proxy configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName dlx
DocumentRoot "C:/deluxe/"
<LocationMatch /drupal/>
ProxyPass               http://localhost/drupal/
ProxyPassReverse        http://localhost/drupal/
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Configure .htaccess on my dlx virtualhost (`C:/deluxe/`):

```
    RewriteRule ^drupal/(.*)$ http://localhost/drupal/$1 [P,L]
```

That's it. It works for me, I hope it also works for you.